# MySQL: prepared Statement in a stored Procedure - parameter error 1064

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, prepared-statement, parameter-passing, mysql-error-1064

I'm creating a sql script for a migration functionality of ours. We want to migrate data from one magento-instance to another (using pure SQL because the import/export of magento is pretty limited).

One of the challenges ist that I want to dynamically alter the AUTO_INCREMENT value of a table  so it doesn't need to be done manually in multiple steps. I want to set the AUTO_INCREMENT value to the current-maximum value of the corresponding column + 1.

I prepared the following stored procedure for this:

```
    DELIMITER $$

    CREATE PROCEDURE alter_auto_inc_customer()
    BEGIN

      SELECT @max := MAX(entity_id)+ 1 FROM customer_entity;

      PREPARE stmt FROM 'ALTER TABLE customer_entity AUTO_INCREMENT = ?';
      EXECUTE stmt USING @max;

    END $$
```

This command runs smoothly. Afterwards the procedure should just be called by a simple statement:

```
CALL alter_auto_inc_customer();
```

When I execute the "call"-statement, I get a 1064 Syntax error. It's probably trivial but I can't figure it out for the life of me...

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '?' at line 1
```

Does anyone have an idea what the issue is?

I need to get this into one or more stored procedures because I need to be able to run similar statements for multiple tables in the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of altering the table structure you can use a trigger to get the max value + 1 before insert data:

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS custom_autoincrement_bi$$

CREATE TRIGGER custom_autoincrement_bi BEFORE INSERT ON customer_entity
FOR each ROW
BEGIN

   SET NEW.entity_id = select max(entity_id) + 1 from customer_entity;

END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

But if you want to alter the table from stored procedure

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE alter_auto_inc_customer()
BEGIN

  SELECT MAX(entity_id) + 1 into @max FROM customer_entity;
  set @sql = concat('ALTER TABLE customer_entity AUTO_INCREMENT = ', @max);
  PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
  EXECUTE stmt ;
  DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;

END $$
```

Comment: Hi, it's a workaround that would do but I'd like to use a procedure. As I said I need to do this with muliple tables and I'd like to handle all with one call (instead of multiple Triggers)

Comment: I modify my answer adding a stored procedure with some changes.

Comment: Your procedure works like a charm. Thank you very much!